# ffmpeg: overlay rotated video with transparency

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing, codec

I'm new to ffmpeg (video encoding in general).

I have two videos one larger than the other. I want to rotate, resize and overlay the shorter video on the larger one at defined coordinates.

So far, I'm doing this:

1. Add alpha channel to both the videos: `ffmpeg -i demo.mov -vcodec qtrle -pix_fmt argb demo.mov`
2. Define fadein, fadeout, scale, overlay, perspective and rotation then output the video: `ffmpeg -y -i demo.mov -i demo2.mov -filter_complex  "[1:v] fade=in:10:1:alpha=1, fade=out:500:1:alpha=1, scale=80:80, perspective=x0=0:y0=0:x1=W:y1=40, rotate=-0.1745:c=none [ov]; [0:v][ov] overlay=100:100 [v]" -map "[v]" out.mov`

In this process, I'm facing a few problems:

1. Am I adding alpha channels the right way?
2. The final output has flickering background in the place where the rotated video has margins.
3. The overlay remains a square. I do not want it to be square, but of the dimension specified by `perspective` filter.

Some of the parameters in the above commands (such as `perspective`,`fade`) are arbitrary.

To give a better perspective of what I'm trying to do: trying to add a video as though it was being played on a phone that is moving.

I have asked about problems on IRC and got this far. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Here is the output: https://youtu.be/yd4UWq5NO5M

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you upload the raw inputs?

Comment: @Mulvya Sure. http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mov_480x360.mov
I'm using the same source for both - background and overlay for convenience.

Comment: I added alpha channel on this input.

Comment: I'll have a closer look later, but there is no alpha channel. The pixel format is yuv420p. Mind you, you don't need an alpha channel for what you're trying to do. In any case, what would the alpha channel be populated with?

Comment: Also, since you're "trying to add a video as though it was being played on a phone that is moving", this is best done in a compositing app with a tracker. Look into Natron - http://natron.fr/ or Fusion - https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/in/products/fusion if you're looking for a free solution. else After Effects.

Comment: **Why I add alpha channel:** when I tried to overlay the video without alpha channel, a black background remained when I faded it out. Adding alpha channel removed it. So, I'm adding the channel so that there are no remains of the overlay when it fades out.

I need to integrate this functionality into my app, so not using third party solutions is nicer :)

Comment: No need for alpha channel. Your last filter should be [0:v][ov] overlay=100:100:eof_action=pass [v]

Comment: Yep! That worked! Now I don't have to worry about large sized intermediate videos. Thanks!
However the flickering issue is still there.

Comment: The weird thing is the flickering almost completely vanishes if I perform the task in two commands i.e. one ffmpeg command to output a MOV with the transformed video with the fades and one command to perform the overlay of that MOV on top of the original. But the identical filterchain for the first step when integrated into a single command, gives flickering.

Comment: I have tried multiple videos. All have been giving the flickering. I haven't tried separating the filter chains though.

Comment: Try this for the first command :  ffmpeg -y -i "input.mov" -vf "format=bgra, perspective=x0=0:y0=0:x1=W:y1=180, fade=in:10:1:alpha=1, fade=out:200:1:alpha=1, scale=-1:80, rotate=-0.1745:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih)" -c:v qtrle output.mov

Comment: And 2nd: ffmpeg -y -i "input.mov" -i "output.mov" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=100:100:eof_action=pass [v]" -map "[v]" final_out.mov

Comment: Flickering a lot. Here: https://youtu.be/ZzLBVRGfn60

Comment: Let me check here again.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the process into two steps worked for me.

See my output using the commands below at http://sendvid.com/g56xjz04

The commands I used:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "video for overlay.mov" -vf "format=bgra, perspective=x0=0:y0=0:x1=W:y1=180, fade=in:10:1:alpha=1, fade=out:200:1:alpha=1, scale=-1:80, rotate=-0.1745:c=none:ow=rotw(-0.1745):oh=roth(-0.1745)" -c:v qtrle overlay.mov

ffmpeg -y -i "base.mov" -i "overlay.mov" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=100:100:eof_action=pass [v]" -map "[v]" final_out.mov
```

I suspect that in the single command complex filterchain, there is some bug or nuance regarding the alpha channel operations that is generating a garbled alpha channel.

If you need a single command, I think your best way forward is to submit a [bug report](https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html) to the ffmpeg team, including the commands and output of both the single command and two-step process.

Comment: Also, ensure that you're using the latest or a fairly recent ffmpeg build.

Comment: I just tested the two commands with these versions: `N-76452-ga97f1e7` and `N-76045-g97be5d4`. Can you tell me which version you are using? Because I'm still getting the flickering.

Comment: I have the N-75573-g1d0487f 64-bit static build from 29/09/2015, taken from this site: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: From the numbers, it seems mine is newer.

Comment: Did you compile it yourself?

Comment: I compiled `N-76452-ga97f1e7` and added `N-76045-g97be5d4` from here - https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media

Comment: Try the latest version from the original source: https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: Should I go for 2.8.1 (downloadable tar) or pull from git? Oh, I just compiled 2.8.1 and it says `No such filter: 'perspective'`

Comment: @DhavanVaidya Always use git, not release.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Okay. I'll do that and post what happens.